# Run GNU parallel commands in different folders

Tags: linux, xargs

I'm trying to run commands in parallel. But these commands need to be run in different directories. How can I achieve this?
Can I do something like this:

```
parallel ::: 'cd platform1 && npm install && npm run build-all'
'cd platform2 && npm install && npm run build-prod'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
(cd platform1 && npm install && npm run build-all && touch flag.1) &
(cd platform2 && npm install && npm run build-prod && touch flag.2) &

while [ !( -f flag.1 -a -f flag.2 ) ]
do sleep 5
done

# All the rest code

####
```

Commands placed inside round brackets (or backticks) are launched inside subshell that is launched in background because of trailing `&`

Comment: so would I write it like this? parallel ::: ('cd platform1 && npm install && npm run build-all')&
('cd platform2 && npm install && npm run build-prod')&

Comment: Commands should be separated by semicolon if you want one-liner: `parallel ::: (pipe1)& ; (pipe2)&;`

Comment: is that best practice or does the semicolon have a purpose?

Comment: and sorry last question. If i want to write some commands after these commands that need to wait for these to finish, how do I do that?

Comment: Semicolon separate commands. It is mandatory if you place more than one command in the line. I've edit my answer.

Comment: the while loop is giving me a syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Refer to the `man [` on your platform.